# How To Delete First X Lines Based On Minimum Lines In File

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with 10,000 lines. Using the following command, I am deleting all lines after line 10,000.

```
sed -i '10000,$ d' file.txt
```

However, now I would like to delete the first X lines so that the file has no more than 10,000 lines.

I think it would be something like this:

```
sed -i '1,$x d' file.txt
```

Where `$x` would be the number of lines over 10,000. I'm a little stuck on how to write the if, then part of it. Or, I was thinking I could use the original command and just `cat` the file in reverse?

For example, if we wanted just 3 lines from the bottom (seems simpler after a few helpful answers):

Input:

```
Example Line 1
Example Line 2
Example Line 3
Example Line 4
Example Line 5
```

Expected Output:

```
Example Line 3
Example Line 4
Example Line 5
```

Of course, if you know a more efficient way to write the command, I would be open to that too. Your positive input is highly appreciated.

Comment: [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

Comment: Ah, sure, I'll add it now haha.

Comment: Why won't a simple `tail -n 3 file` work for you?

Comment: Yup, @kaylum provided that. I went with the `sed` option because it was inplace and already what I was struggling with.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Don't get lured into using it for other stuff (e.g. deleting sections of a file) just because it has a `-i` option that tells it to create a temp file on the fly instead of you having to name it. Just use the right tool for each job and if you have to name the temp file yourself it's just not a big deal compared to having to figure out what convoluted sed syntax hoops to jump through for every job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity, I would reverse the file, keep the first 10000 lines, then re-reverse the file.

It makes saving the file in-place a touch more complicated

```
source=file.txt
temp=$(mktemp)
tac "$source" | sed '10000 q' | tac > "$temp" && mv "$temp" "$source"
```

Without reversing the file, you'd count the number of lines and do some arithmetic:

```
sed -i "1,$(( $(wc -l < file.txt) - 10000 )) d" file.txt
```

Comment: Why not just `tail`?

Comment: @hidefromkgb, I'd vote for a `tail` answer if you provide it

Comment: What shell are you using? `/bin/sh`? what's the output of `echo "$(($(wc -l < file.txt)-10000))`?

Answer (score 10):

[tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) can do exactly what you want.

```
tail -n 10000 file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

To keep the first 10000 lines :

```
head -n 10000 file.txt
```

To keep the last 10000 lines :

```
tail -n 10000 file.txt
```

Test with your file Example

```
tail -n 3 file.txt
Example Line 3
Example Line 4
Example Line 5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{a[NR%n]=$0} END{for (i=NR+1;i<=(NR+n);i++) print a[i%n]}' file
Example Line 3
Example Line 4
Example Line 5
```

Add `-i inplace` if you have GNU awk and want to do "inplace" editing.

Comment: I see how that makes your life easier. Thanks Ed.

Answer (score 2):

`tac file.txt | sed "$x q" | tac | sponge file.txt`

The `sponge` command is useful here in avoiding an additional temporary file.

Comment: if you're reversing the file, then you want to keep the *first* 10000 lines.

Comment: The question asks about deleting the first X lines so that the resulting file has no more than 10,000 lines.  This command leaves the last 9,999 lines when `x` is 10000.

Comment: Suppose you want to keep the last 5 lines. Does this do it?`seq 20 | tac | sed '1,5d' | tac` ? No, it *removes* the last 5 lines. You need `sed -n '1,5p'` or `sed 5q` in the pipeline instead.

Comment: But as mentioned above, `tail` seems like the better option here.

Answer (score 2):

`tail -10000 <<<"$(cat file.txt)" > file.txt`

Okay, not «just» `tail`, but this way it`s capable of inplace truncation.

Comment: Like the inplace use.

Comment: That's fugly. But it works. I'd use `$(< file.txt)` if the shell supports it. Saves a few microseconds.

Comment: Are you SURE it works? What guarantees the shell won't do `> file.txt` before it does `cat file.txt`? There's nothing could convince me to execute that code on any important data.

Comment: The shell guarantees that I/O redirections are processed left-to-right. However, how here-strings actually work is murky enough that I wouldn't assume that `cat` actually has to complete before moving on to the next redirection.

Comment: @chepner Here-strings are just a variant of here-documents, right? And the official manual states that «*All* of the lines read up to that point [the terminating line] are *then* used as the standard input» (see [3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#3.6.7)).

Comment: As far as I know, that just indicates *what* will be used, without addressing *how* the string is generated. The shell could fork itself and write the contents to a temporary file, then read from that.